# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.'

Tags: docker, tcp

I have a tcp listener in a local app and a docker container with another app inside. In the docker container I expose the port 5555:5555 for establish a socket between the app inse docker to the tcp listner who is listening in 127.0.0.1:5555.

The problem is that when I expose the port in the docker container (-p 5555:5555) windows exclude this port.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlRTZ.png)

that's why I can't run my tcp listener, reason why I get the System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution for this, so at the end I created a new container for my tcp server, and I established a network between containers.

```
docker network create --driver bridge nat
```

Defining the networks in the docker-composes and giving to my tcpServer a static ip

```
services:
  tcpServer:
    networks:
      test:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.192.157
    ....

networks:
  test:
    external:
      name: nat
```

I tried first to set up the host network, but I realized that this funcionality is not available in windows.

- The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server

[Docker network documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/)